# How can multiple threads (that are waiting on a condition variable) acquire the relevant lock when condition_all() is called?

Tags: multithreading, mutex, condition-variable

From theory, a waiting thread (let's say Thread_1) first acquires a mutex, then waits on the condition variable by calling wait(). The call to wait() immediately unlocks the mutex. When the other thread (let's say Thread_2) calls notify(), the waiting thread  (Thread_1) is waken up and the same mutex is locked before the wait(..) call returns.

Now let's say multiple threads are waiting on a condition variable at a given time (let's say Thread_1, Thread_2 and Thread_3). Now another thread (Thread_4) calls notify_all(), that will notify all 3 threads that are waiting for the condition variable. When they are waken up, how can all 3 of them lock the mutex, that should happen before the wait(...) call returns? Only one thread (out of the 3 waiting threads) can acquire the mutex. Then what is the purpose of notify_all(), if it can unblock only one thread? What is the difference in results (from waiting threads' point of view) between notify() and notify_all()?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9015748/whats-the-difference-between-notify-all-and-notify-one-of-stdcondition-va

Answer (score 3):

> How can all three of them lock the mutex?

They lock it one at a time, just like always.

A `wait(...)` function could be implemented like this:

```
def wait(cond_var, mutex):
    tricky_internal_wait(cond_var, mutex)
    lock(mutex)
```

The `tricky_internal_wait(c,m)` function would *atomically* unlock the mutex and block the calling thread on a queue associated with `cond_var`, but there's no reason why the `lock(mutex)` call at the end of it needs to be any different from the ordinary `lock(mutex)`.

When the `cond_var` is notified in the example above, the thread would wake up, and then it would call `lock(mutex)`, and then if some other thread already had locked the mutex, the OS would block the caller on a queue associated with `mutex`. The caller could not return from the `wait()` call until it returned from the `lock()` call, and it could not return from `lock()` until the mutex became available and the caller acquired it.  Just like how `lock()` always works.

A *practical* implementation of `wait(c,m)` probably would do things more efficiently: It probably would move the thread directly from the `cond_var` queue to the `mutex` queue without ever waking the thread up if the `mutex` already was in use by some other thread.

---

> Then what is the purpose of notify_all(), if it can unblock only one thread?

It *doesn't* unblock only one. It unblocks all of them,...

...One-at-a-time.

Suppose that some thread T calls `notify_all(cond_var)` while threads X, Y, and Z all are awaiting the condition in `foobar()`:

```
def foobar():
    lock(mutex)
    while condition_is_not_satisfied():
        wait(cond_var, mutex)
    do_some_thing_that_requires_condition_to_be_satisfied()
    unlock(mutex)
```

Maybe thread Z will be the first to return from the `wait()` call. It will check again to see that the condition really is satisfied, and then it will do the thing, and then it will unlock the `mutex` and return from `foobar()`.

Until thread Z unlocks the mutex and returns, threads X and Y will be unable to return from the `wait()` call.

Maybe after Z unlocks the mutex, the next one to return from the wait() will be X. X will then check to see if the condition is satisfied. Maybe the action of Z means that the condition is *not* satisifed any longer. In that case, X will `wait()` again and the `wait()` call will release the mutex.  Or, maybe the condition still is satisifed, and X will do the thing, and explicitly unlock the mutex and return from `foobar()`.

Either way, thread X will release the mutex, and then thread Y will be able to return from the `wait()` call...

...and so it goes.

Comment: Thank you Solomon for your answer. Really appreciate it.