# Two questions on std::condition_variables

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, race-condition, stdthread

I have been trying to figure out [std::condition_variables](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) and I am particularly confused by `wait()` and whether to use `notify_all` or `notify_one`.

First, I've written some code and attached it below. Here's a short explanation: `Collection` is a class that holds onto a bunch of `Counter` objects. These `Counter` objects have a `Counter::increment()` method, which needs to be called on all the objects, over and over again. To speed everything up, `Collection` also maintains a thread pool to distribute the work over, and sends out all the work with its `Collection::increment_all()` method.

These threads don't need to communicate with each other, and there are usually many more `Counter` objects than there are threads. It's fine if one thread processes more than `Counter`s than others, just as long as all the work gets done. Adding work to the queue is easy and only needs to be done in the "main" thread. As far as I can see, the only bad thing that can happen is if other methods (e.g. `Collection::printCounts`) are allowed to be called on the counters in the middle of the work being done.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <queue>


class Counter{
private:
    int m_count;
public:
    Counter() : m_count(0) {}
    void increment() { 
        m_count ++; 
    }
    int getCount() const { return m_count; }
};


class Collection{
public:
    Collection(unsigned num_threads, unsigned num_counters) 
    : m_shutdown(false)
    {
        // start workers
        for(size_t i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i){
            m_threads.push_back(std::thread(&Collection::work, this)); 
        }

        // intsntiate counters
        for(size_t j = 0; j < num_counters; ++j){
            m_counters.emplace_back();
        }
    }

    ~Collection() 
    { 
        m_shutdown = true;
        for(auto& t : m_threads){
            if(t.joinable()){
                t.join();
            }
        }
    }

    void printCounts() {

        // wait for work to be done
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m_mtx);
        m_work_complete.wait(lk); // q2: do I need a while lop?  

        // print all current counters
        for(const auto& cntr : m_counters){
            std::cout << cntr.getCount() << ", ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }

    void increment_all() 
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mtx);
        m_work_complete.wait(lock);
        for(size_t i = 0; i < m_counters.size(); ++i){
            m_which_counters_have_work.push(i);
        }

    }


private:    
    void work()
    {
        while(!m_shutdown){

            bool action = false;
            unsigned which_counter;
            {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mtx);
                if(m_which_counters_have_work.size()){
                    which_counter = m_which_counters_have_work.front();
                    m_which_counters_have_work.pop();
                    action = true;
                }else{
                    m_work_complete.notify_one(); // q1: notify_all
                }
            }

            if(action){
                m_counters[which_counter].increment();
            }
        }   
    }



    std::vector<Counter> m_counters;
    std::vector<std::thread> m_threads;
    std::condition_variable m_work_complete;
    std::mutex m_mtx;
    std::queue<unsigned> m_which_counters_have_work;
    bool m_shutdown;

};

int main() {

    int num_threads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency()-1;
    int num_counters = 10;
    Collection myCollection(num_threads, num_counters);

    myCollection.printCounts();
    myCollection.increment_all();
    myCollection.printCounts();

    myCollection.increment_all();
    myCollection.printCounts();

    return 0;
}
```

I compile this on Ubuntu 18.04 with `g++ -std=c++17 -pthread thread_pool.cpp -o tp && ./tp` I think the code accomplishes all of those objectives, but a few questions remain:

1. I am using `m_work_complete.wait(lk)` to make sure the work is finished before I start printing all the new counts. **Why do I sometimes see this written inside a `while` loop, or with a second argument as a lambda predicate function?** [These docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait) mention spurious wake ups. If a spurious wake up occurs, does that mean `printCounts` could prematurely print? If so, I don't want that. I just want to ensure the work queue is empty before I start using the numbers that should be there.
2. I am using `m_work_complete.notify_all` instead of `m_work_complete.notify_one`. I've read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9015748/whats-the-difference-between-notify-all-and-notify-one-of-stdcondition-va), and I don't think it matters--only the main thread is going to be blocked by this. **Is it faster to use `notify_one` just so the other threads don't have to worry about it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `std::condition_variable` is not really a *condition variable*, it's more of a synchronization tool for reaching a certain condition. What that condition is is up to the programmer, and it should still be checked after each `condition_variable` wake-up, since it can wake-up spuriously, or "too early", when the desired condition isn't yet reached.

   On POSIX systems, `condition_variable::wait()` delegates to [`pthread_cond_wait`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_cond_wait.3p.html), which is susceptible to spurious wake-up (see "Condition Wait Semantics" in the Rationale section). On Linux, `pthread_cond_wait` is in turn implemented via a [`futex`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/futex.2.html), which is again susceptible to spurious wake-up.

   So yes you still need a flag (protected by the same mutex) or some other way to check that the work is actually complete. A convenient way to do this is by wrapping the check in a predicate and passing it to the `wait()` function, which would loop for you until the predicate is satisfied.
2. `notify_all` unblocks all threads waiting on the condition variable; `notify_one` unblocks just one (or at least one, to be precise). If there are more than one waiting threads, and they are equivalent, i.e. either one can handle the condition fully, and if the condition is sufficient to let just one thread continue (as in submitting a work unit to a thread pool), then `notify_one` would be more efficient since it won't unblock other threads unnecessarily for them to only notice no work to be done and going back to waiting. If you ever only have one waiter, then there would be no difference between `notify_one` and `notify_all`.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple: Use `notify()` when;

1. There is no reason why more than one thread needs to know about the event. (E.g., use `notify()` to announce the availability of an item that a worker thread will "consume," and thereby make the item unavailable to other workers)
   ***AND***
2. There is no *wrong* thread that could be awakened. (E.g., you're probably safe if all of the threads are `wait()`ing in the same line of the same exact function.)

Use `notify_all()` in all other cases.